# Is the memory allocated with 'new' for object created with 'gtk_list_store_newv'

Tags: gtk

I use GTK to create GUI with buttons, lists etc.
In some classes I have private members of type GtkListStore* and I use 'gtk_list_store_newv' to initialize those pointers.
The function 'gtk_list_store_newv' creates new GtkListStore and returns GtkListStore*. GTK documentation says 'Returns a new GtkListStore'.
Is the memory for newly created object created with 'new' operator? If it is so then should I explicitly released with 'delete', e.g. in a custom object destructor?

```
class What {
  public:
    What();
    ~What();
  private:
    GtkListStore* whatWhat;
};

// this constructor uses 'gtk_list_store_newv' to initialize the member
What::What() {
  // some variables to define input arguments for the function
  whatWhat = gtk_list_store_newv(// the arguments here...);
}

// SHOULD THIS EXPLICIT DESTRUCTOR USE 'delete'
What::~What() {
  delete whatWhat;  // do I need this 'delete' to release memory
}
```

Just for the record, when I use 'delete' this way no crashes occur neither any warnings.

Comment: If you're doing C++, use [GTKmm](https://gtkmm.org/en/), the C++ bindings for GTK+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `GtkListStore` [is a subclass of `GObject`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListStore.html#GtkListStore.object-hierarchy), and GObjects are reference counted. Use `g_object_unref(whatWhat);`

`delete` may work for you, but that's only by coincidence. It will crash somewhere down the line.